# Count rolling window unique values with duplicate dates pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

If I have a pandas DataFrame like this

| date | person_active |
| --- | --- |
| 22/2 | John |
| 22/2 | Marie |
| 22/2 | Mark |
| 23/2 | John |
| 24/2 | Mark |
| 24/2 | Marie |

how do I count in a rolling window based on time the unique values in `person_active`, **for example: 2 days rolling window**, so it ends up like this:

| date | person_active | people_active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22/2 | John | 3 |
| 22/2 | Marie | 3 |
| 22/2 | Mark | 3 |
| 23/2 | John | 3 |
| 24/2 | Mark | 3 |
| 24/2 | Marie | 3 |

The main issue here is that I have duplicate entries on `date` for each person so a simple `df.rolling('2d',on='date').count()` won't do the job.

EDIT: Please consider implementation in a big dataset and how the time to compute will scale, the solution needs to be ideally applicable in a real-world environment so if it takes too long to compute it's not that useful.

Comment: Why does 23/2 have 4 active people? If you're counting *unique* people, shouldn't it be 3: John, Marie and Mark? You should also update your question to have a more representative example showing the "duplicate entries on date for each person"

Comment: This was a typo, just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, try:

```
#convert to datetime if needed
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%d/%m")

#convert string name to categorical codes for numerical aggegation
df["people"] = pd.Categorical(df["person_active"]).codes

#compute the rolling unique count
df["people_active"] = (df.rolling("2D", on="date")["people"]
                         .agg(lambda x: x.nunique())
                         .groupby(df["date"])
                         .transform("max")
                       )

#drop the unneccessary column
df = df.drop("people", axis=1)

>>> df
        date person_active  people_active
0 1900-02-22          John            3.0
1 1900-02-22         Marie            3.0
2 1900-02-22          Mark            3.0
3 1900-02-23          John            3.0
4 1900-02-24          Mark            3.0
5 1900-02-24         Marie            3.0
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround but it's way too slow on a large dataset

Answer (score 0):

Group by date, count unique values and then you're good to go:

```
df.groupby('date').nunique().rolling('2d').sum()
```

Comment: Again, this would count duplicate people if the same people are active across different days of the window, so this solution doesn't count the unique values.